# splitting a column in 2 in R

Tags: r

I have a df like

```
ind1.id ind2.id group   wang
02_1    02_1    1205    -0.2999
02_1    02_11   1205    -0.1688
02_1    02_12   1205    -0.0873
02_1    02_13   1205    -0.0443
02_1    02_14   1205    -0.1415
```

and I would like to split the group column so that it is like this

```
ind1.id ind2.id group1  group2  wang
02_1    02_1    12  05  -0.2999
02_1    02_11   12  05  -0.1688
02_1    02_12   12  05  -0.0873
02_1    02_13   12  05  -0.0443
02_1    02_14   12  05  -0.1415
```

I've messed around with strsplit and stuff but haven't managed to get every far.

Thanks.

Comment: please check your desired result. It does not seem right.

Comment: Can you explain why first 3 observations, the group 1205 becomes 12 and 5, then 4th example group 1205 becomes 12 and 0, then last example group 1205 becomes 12 and 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 df %>%
   as_tibble() %>%
   separate(group, c("group1", "group2"), sep = "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar, cut after first two digits.

```
df %>% separate(group,c("group1","group2"),sep = "(?<=^\\d\\d)",remove=T)
```

Result:

```
   ind1.id ind2.id group1 group2    wang
1:    02_1    02_1     12     05 -0.2999
2:    02_1   02_11     12     05 -0.1688
3:    02_1   02_12     12     05 -0.0873
4:    02_1   02_13     12     05 -0.0443
5:    02_1   02_14     12     05 -0.1415
```